# Is it posssible to save text in nano with one keypress

Tags: nano

I use nano as my favorite text editor.

I was able to save my documents by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But is there a way to save the document directly by pressing some key, if I'm sure I would like to save the document to the same name as before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

- Edit your `.nanorc` file
- Add line: `set tempfile`

Now, after you finish editting your file, just press `Ctrl + X`, `nano` then quit and automatically save your file.

Answer (score 2):

Referenced from : [Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nano/Basics_Guide)
Saving and exiting

If you want to save the changes you've made, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. To exit `nano`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. If you ask `nano` to exit from a modified file, it will ask you if you want to save it. Just press <kbd>n</kbd> in case you don't, or <kbd>y</kbd> in case you do. It will then ask you for a filename. Just type it in and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you accidentally confirmed that you want to save the file, but you actually don't, you can always cancel by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> when you're prompted for a filename.

Comment: Ctrl-O is equivalent to F3 and they both prompt to confirm the filename. My understanding of the question is that novice wishes to avoid this prompt for confirming the filename.